# How to build aggregations on joined values with windowing functions most performant?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I got a problem with building aggregations on joined values with windowing functions. Simplified it looks like that:

I got the following tables:

```
  CREATE TABLE movies (
    id SERIAL,
    name VARCHAR,
    year INT,
    genre VARCHAR,
    country VARCHAR
  );

  CREATE TABLE tags (
    id SERIAL,
    name VARCHAR
  );

  CREATE TABLE movies_tags (
    id SERIAL,
    movie_id INT,
    tag_id INT
  );
```

Now I want to do the following statement:

```
  SELECT m.*, array_agg(t.name) AS tags
  FROM movies m
  LEFT JOIN movies_tags mt ON mt.movie_id = m.id
  LEFT JOIN tags t ON t.id = mt.tag_id
  ORDER BY m.name
  LIMIT 10
```

Because of the aggregation in the select, all movies get joined with all tags before selecting the top 10 out of that big join. My goal is it to get the aggregation only on the top 10 movies for performance reasons. So what I did was this:

```
  WITH top_movies AS (
    SELECT m.*
    FROM movies m
    ORDER BY m.name
    LIMIT 10
  )
  SELECT tm.*, array_agg(t.name) AS tags
  FROM top_movies tm
  LEFT JOIN movies_tags mt ON mt.movie_id = tm.id
  LEFT JOIN tags t ON t.id = mt.tag_id
```

The performance is much better. But I got another problem. The final goal is it to create a form of reusable components like a function in Postgres or a named query in an ORM like Rails's Active Record which I can modify dynamically afterward according to my needs for example like this:

```
  SELECT * FROM my_top_movies_with_tags() AS tm
  WHERE tm.country = 'USA' AND tm.year <= 1995
  LIMIT 10;
```

Therefore I have to modify my SQL statement that the movie selection is the outer query which however still limits the joining of the tags to the top n movies I want as a result.

To accomplish this, I experimented with lateral joins and did this:

```
  SELECT m.*, lat.tags FROM movies m
  LATERAL (
    SELECT array_agg(t.name) AS tags
    FROM movies_tags mt
    JOIN tags t ON t.id = mt.tag_id
    WHERE mt.movie_id = m.id
  ) AS lat
  ORDER BY m.name
  LIMIT 10;
```

That gives me the flexibility to modify it dynamically afterward but is performance wise much worse.

Is there any other way to accomplish my goals that I'm not aware of?

My goals summarized:

1. Build aggregates (`array_agg`) only on the `LIMIT`ed movie set and not on the whole movies table.
2. Stays modifiable through appending of `WHERE`, `ORDER` and `LIMIT` statements.
3. Performs well.

Answer (score 1):

What about using [row_number](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html) to emulate `LIMIT`?

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 
        m.*, 
        array_agg(t.name) AS tags,
        row_number() OVER(ORDER BY m.name) AS rownum
    FROM 
        movies m
        LEFT JOIN movies_tags mt ON mt.movie_id = m.id
        LEFT JOIN tags t ON t.id = mt.tag_id
    --There're must be a GROUP BY here
    ) AS tmp
WHERE rownum <= 10;
```

Also, please consider [this article](https://blog.2ndquadrant.com/postgresql-ctes-are-optimization-fences/) when using CTE's on performance critical queries.

Comment: Thank you for this article! The using of ruw_number is very interesting. I will experiment a bit with it and compare it to the benchmarks I have from my other approaches.

Answer (score 0):

You can add form inputs to a temporary table and use your this table for filtering.

```
 CREATE TEMP TABLE temp_inputs
  (
     country VARCHAR(80),
     year int
  )
  ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS;


WITH top_movies AS (
    SELECT m.*
    FROM movies m
    ORDER BY m.name
    LIMIT 10
  )
  SELECT tm.*, array_agg(t.name) AS tags
  FROM tmovies tm, temp_inputs
  LEFT JOIN movies_tags mt ON mt.movie_id = tm.id
  LEFT JOIN tags t ON t.id = mt.tag_id
  and tm.country = temp_inputs.country AND tm.year <=  temp_inputs.year
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. But I don't understand in which way this improves my query. This kind of filtering could be done with a regular where statement. Or does it modifies the Common Table Expression somehow?

Comment: By using temporary table, runtime value of the parameter will be embedded into the query so the dynamic seek will not be required.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on this or give me a link to some more information on this? It sounds interesting, but I'm not sure how the workflow should work exactly. How and when do I get the values into the temp table? Do I have to do a regular insert of a row into the temp table which is used automatically in my main statement? As far as I have read about the `ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS`, it deletes the content of the temp table at the end of a transaction. So do I have to wrap the statement into a transaction to make sure the temp table is empty at the beginning?

Comment: I only find below link, http://www.andrewleesmith.co.uk/2017/03/03/using-sql-servers-parameter-embedding-optimisation/ It can give an idea. I suggest you to inspect execution plan of your query. Unfortunately,  there is no obsolete solution for query optimization. If you close your connection after each search, you don't need to check the temp table.